# Can a Converted to Path again converted to text in xd?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, interface-design, adobe-xd

If I converted a text into a path, then is it possible that I can convert it back again to text in Adobe Xd?

If not then how to deal with this if I want a text back? is there any possible ways to tackle it?
Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a (paid) plug in by Astute Graphics that can convert outlined text back to editable text. It is called Vector First Aid and is part of their subscription based plug in package (which are all very good). You must have the exact same font installed on your system to convert it back to editable text. While this can be handy in certain situations, if you have the font then why not just recreate the text.

Comment: @Kyle well to be honest firstaid does recreate the text but automates many of the recreation aspects.

Comment: @Kyle Yeah, but that plugin is for illustrator only, not Adobe XD, and it doesn't actually convert outlines back into editable text; it automates the process of replacing it with editable text, and you must have the exact font already installed. Sure it's nice, but not magic, since any human operator can do that anyway. It'll just take a little longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Once text has been converted to outlines the operation can not be reversed.

If you need text back, your only choice is to delete and *recreate* text.

This holds true for *all* Adobe apps once text has been converted to outlines.